# UIActivityIndicatorView Starting and Stopping

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, ios4

I have an activity indicator that needs to be activated as soon as a button is clicked and then stopped after a conditional statement...

I've looked at ways online to implement this but all i can find is setting them with webviews not simply turning them on and then off again.... below is my basic problem

```
-(IBAction)SavePassword:(id)sender{
\\start animating activity indicator
if(post recieved no errors){
\\stop animating activity indicator
}
\\else{
return the user error
}
```

if anyone can help it would be awesome :)

Comment: Is you action asynchrone ? Because if it is you have to stop the animation in your callback.

Comment: i'm using asihttp and it is just a syncroneous request... maybe if i change it to async it will work..

Answer (score 10):

it pretty straight forward...
create an outlet and connect it in the interface builder..

```
@property(nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView *activityIndicator;
```

in the implementation just use these two methods to start and stop the animation...

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

and

```
[self.activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Comment: thanks this was really helpful. But i have set the indicator to hidden.... so it needs to appear now when the button is pressed...

Comment: the activity indicator has a property 'hidesWhenStopped' set it to 'YES' (or 'TRUE')...

Comment: @MrPink How about you read some basic tutorial about iOS and Objective C before going any further?

Comment: a month has past since then. guess it gives you kicks putting down people who want to learn from others...

Comment: @lukya He was directing that at TheBlack no doubt.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems with hiding and showing when it was in the same method. By setting the visibility it will not instantly change it but only at the end of the method. So in your case it will show the indicator (technically not on screen) do some stuff and then hide it again. For the user it will never appear. You can try to perform the action on a background thread but not sure if it's thread safe enough. (Because typically all drawing functions like `.hidden` must occur on the main thread)

```
[activityIndicator performSelectorInBackground:@selector(startAnimating) withObject:nil];
```

Comment: you told that you have to set it visible then you would need to wrap another method around `[indicator setHidden:NO];` because `YES` is not an object. And then call this new method which only sets the visibility.

Answer (score 0):

place a activity indicator with help of interface builder.

then make an iboulet of that indicator.

```
IBoulet UIActivityIndicator *ac;
```

Then declare property and senthesize it

```
 @property(nonatomic,retain) UIActivityIndicator *ac;
```

in implementation class synethesize it.

```
   @synthesize ac;
```

then

```
[ac startAnimating];
```

and where u want to stop

```
[ac stopAnimating];
```